# Can I copy files in origin branch directly without making local working copy

Tags: git, azure, devops

We are using azure devops git as our repository and after each release, we need to copy (without deleting) one of the file from one folder to another with in the same branch. I am wondering if there is any way i can achieve this without having to make a local working copy on the hosted agent.

Any help/guidance is highly appreciated.